# Comparing pandas Dataframe columns values one by one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

df

```
        Date    Factory I1  D1  I2  D2  I3  D3

   0    1701    West    0   0   0   0   10  0

   1    1701    East    39  0   83  15  3   15

   2    1701    West    0   0   0   10  15  0
```

I want this:

```
 If D2>I2 Then I3=I2+I3,D3=D2+D3,I2=D2=0

 If D3>I3 Then I2=I2+I3,D2=D2+D3,I3=D3=0
```

else no change

So the data should be like this:

df

```
     Date   Factory I1  D1  I2  D2  I3  D3

     0  1701    West    0   0   0   0   10  0

     1  1701    East    39  0   86  30  0   0

     2  1701    West    0   0   0   0   15  10
```

How can I do?Please help~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
m1 = df.D2 > df.I2
m2 = df.D3 > df.I3
df = df.mask(m1, df.assign(I3=df.I2+df.I3, D3=df.D2+df.D3, I2=0, D2=0))
df = df.mask(m2, df.assign(I2=df.I2+df.I3, D2=df.D2+df.D3, I3=0, D3=0))
print (df)
   Date Factory  I1  D1  I2  D2  I3  D3
0  1701    West   0   0   0   0  10   0
1  1701    East  39   0  86  30   0   0
2  1701    West   0   0   0   0  15  10
```

If there are columns with spaces:

```
m1 = df.D2 > df.I2
m2 = df.D3 > df.I3

def f1(x):
    df['I3']=df.I2+df.I3 
    df['D3']=df.D2+df.D3 
    df['I2'] = df['D2'] = 0
    return df

def f2(x):
    df['I2']=df.I2+df.I3 
    df['D2']=df.D2+df.D3 
    df['I3'] = df['D3'] = 0
    return df

df = df.mask(m1, f1)
df = df.mask(m2, f2)
print (df)
   Date Factory  I1  D1  I2  D2  I3  D3
0  1701    West   0   0  10   0   0   0
1  1701    East  39   0  86  30   0   0
2  1701    West   0   0  15  10   0   0
```

Or if want use `assign` (`I3` was changed to `I 3`):

```
m1 = df['D2'] > df['I2']
m2 = df['D3'] > df['I 3']

d1 = {'I 3': lambda x: x['I2'] + x['I 3'],'D3':lambda x: x['D2']+x['D3'],'I2':0,'D2':0}
d2 = {'I2': lambda x: x['I2'] + x['I 3'],'D2':lambda x: x['D2']+x['D3'],'I3':0,'D3':0}
df = df.mask(m1, df.assign(**d1))
df = df.mask(m2, df.assign(**d2))
print (df)
   Date Factory  I1  D1  I2  D2  I 3  D3
0  1701    West   0   0   0   0   10   0
1  1701    East  39   0  86  30    3   0
2  1701    West   0   0   0   0   15  10
```

Comment: another question：Now the columns names are like I3，D3. When they come to be Input third ， Defect third，how can this work？ there is a space in columns name…

Answer (score 0):

One can use easily understandable `for` loop and work over each row:

```
newvals = []
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    ROW = df.iloc[i,:]
    if ROW.D2>ROW.I2:
        ROW.I3=ROW.I2+ROW.I3
        ROW.D3=ROW.D2+ROW.D3
        ROW.I2=ROW.D2=0 
    if ROW.D3>ROW.I3:
        ROW.I2=ROW.I2+ROW.I3
        ROW.D2=ROW.D2+ROW.D3
        ROW.I3=ROW.D3=0
    newvals.append(list(ROW))
newdf = pd.DataFrame(data=newvals, columns=df.columns)
print(newdf)
```

Output:

```
   Date Factory  I1  D1  I2  D2  I3  D3
0  1701    West   0   0   0   0  10   0
1  1701    East  39   0  86  30   0   0
2  1701    West   0   0   0   0  15  10
```

Comment: In my opinion possible solution, but the best in pandas is avoid loops, because slow.

Comment: Yes，it’s easier to understand but as jezrael says，it’s not fast. TKU all the same！

Comment: What did you mean by 'one by one' in your title?